# cannot find name when running AutoExec macro

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

In Access I created a Function within a Module.

I need to execute this module when the Access application first opens.

In the AutoExec macro, I added the action `[RunCode]` and wrote the name of the function from this module in `[Function Name]` but when I run the application I am getting the following error:
[image: access error msg]

Comment: Make sure that you include the parentheses after the function name in the `RunCode` step, e.g., `DsnLessLinkTable()`.

Comment: thanks @GordThompson for the reply, it worked for both parentheses () and double quotes " ", which one i can consider correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a function, you should always include a set of parenthesis at the end:

```
DsnLessLinkTable()
```

This is the proper way to reference a function, and becomes important if you are ever passing variables to a function, so it's good practice to always use that syntax.